# Custom empty Error message in lightning-input-address

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components

I'm working in LWC form which has `lightning-input` and `lightning-input-address`.

In `lightning-input` when the value is missing, displaying the error message by using `message-when-value-missing`.

The same when i Used for `lightning-input-address`, It's not working and It's still shows `Complete this field.` error Message.

```
    <lightning-input label="Phone" value={familyPhone} onchange={handleChange}
                                            name="familyPhone" message-when-value-missing=" " required>
                                        </lightning-input>

<lightning-input-address address-label="Address" street-label="Street"
                                            city-label="City" country-label="Country" province-label="State"
                                            postal-code-label="PostalCode" street={billingStreetval}
                                            city={billingCityval} country={billingCountryval} province={billingStateval}
                                            postal-code={billingPostalval} onchange={handlefamilyChange} message-when-value-missing="Address is Mandatory"
                                            required>
                                        </lightning-input-address>
```

Expecting Like Below, When the Value is empty we need to Highlight the input address field like below. Thanks in Advance.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

`lightning-input-address` does not support `message-when-value-missing`. 
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-input-address/specification

You can use setCustomValidityForField instead

[image]

`lightning-input` supports it.
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:input/specification

Comment: Mert, I'm trying in Playground https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/qB4CCQQIm/10/edit

Can you  please help me on this.